# Changing all strings in a CSV column to a list of integers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Currently im working with pandas to change a CSV column of strings:

```
"3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80"
```

into a list of ints:

```
[3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80]
```

would anyone know how to do this? 
ideally I would like to rewrite this into the same CSV file im pulling this data from, but I suppose I can just add .to_csv to the end of what I must do

any suggestions would be appreciated! thanks!

UPDATE: 
More of the data working with in a CSV
[CVS DATASET](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/279786369902051328/626821798453051394/Capture.PNG)

Here is a reproducible example

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

databasefile = "I:\Github\ClubKeno\Keno Project\Database\..\LotteryDatabase.csv"

def dataSort():
    db = pd.read_csv(databasefile, skip_blank_lines=True,
                     names=['Draw_Number', 'Winning_Numbers', 'Extra_Numbers', 'Kicker'], header=0)
    db.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    # converting data types
    db['Winning_Numbers'] = list(map(int, pd.Series.str.split(",")))
    print(db['Winning_Numbers'])

datasort()
```

[CSV FILE](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/279786369902051328/626832762858373140/LotteryDatabase.csv)

#### Data:

```py
 Draw_Number                                              Winning_Numbers  Extra_Numbers  Kicker
     1500844    3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80            NaN       2
     1500845    6,7,11,12,13,17,18,23,29,30,39,42,47,50,51,56,62,63,66,75            NaN       2
     1500846    2,9,10,12,14,18,24,28,38,40,41,44,50,55,57,61,65,68,72,76            NaN       1
     1500847   9,10,22,25,28,36,40,45,46,47,52,54,57,58,59,65,69,70,74,79            NaN       2
     1500848    7,9,13,14,16,17,18,19,24,25,27,34,40,41,42,47,49,50,53,71            NaN       2
     1500849       3,4,6,7,9,16,32,35,36,48,49,51,54,61,63,66,67,68,73,74            NaN       2
     1500850  15,16,17,18,21,23,26,31,32,44,45,46,47,54,56,57,58,64,75,79            NaN       2
     1500851   8,13,15,17,19,22,25,28,29,31,33,34,37,41,46,47,53,54,63,64            NaN       1
     1500852     5,7,8,15,20,23,24,26,27,34,40,46,53,58,60,65,66,68,69,74            NaN       1
     1500853   1,13,15,16,17,19,21,37,39,46,47,50,53,54,57,61,67,71,72,76            NaN       5
     1500854   8,15,18,22,28,31,33,34,35,39,40,46,47,57,65,67,69,74,76,78            NaN       2
     1500855     2,5,8,12,17,18,20,21,26,31,40,43,46,58,62,64,69,74,76,79            NaN       1
     1500856    2,9,17,22,25,27,29,39,42,43,49,52,61,64,67,69,71,75,79,80            NaN       2
     1500857     4,5,9,11,15,18,22,31,32,33,42,45,48,58,60,61,65,69,70,73            NaN       2
     1500858    3,9,10,14,16,29,37,40,42,46,52,53,54,55,56,57,72,74,79,80            NaN       1
     1500859  11,12,16,19,20,27,28,32,37,44,46,54,58,59,62,66,69,75,77,78            NaN       1
     1500860     3,6,7,11,17,19,23,24,30,31,32,33,42,48,49,57,68,69,70,73            NaN       5
```

Comment: `list(map(int, s.split(",")))`?

Comment: In case of trying to implement that with my problem I got a few errors, In my case I tried to do this
```python
db['Winning_Numbers'] = list(map(int, pd.Series.str.split(",")))
```
In this case I would assume I am trying to grab the column from my data frame 'Winning_Numbers' and am following with what you said of doing some sort of cast to make it a list of integers, however s. showed up as a unresolved refrence so I tried to use Pandas Split

Comment: Could add a sample of your input data and also your expected output? It will make things clearer.

Comment: @DanielMesejo [CVS DATA](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/279786369902051328/626821798453051394/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Better post a [mcve].

Comment: Will be added in main question

Comment: @Goyo There you go

Comment: You didn't define `db`. Anyway what do you expect `pd.Series.str.split(",")` to do?

Comment: Sorry in the code I missed defining that, didnt want to post my whole file, It is posted now. this was suggested earlier to turn the data from a string of integers into a list of integers, this has had no effect @Goyo

Comment: Did you try simple solution such as `db['Winning_Numbers'] = db['Winning_Numbers'].str.split(",")` ?

Comment: @bkyada yes that works by adding the actual list but now it is something like "[1,2,3,4,5]"

Comment: @Timberghost_ Issue is with how you are storing your object again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the `converters` parameter of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('LotteryDatabase.csv', converters={'Winning_Numbers': eval}) 

 Draw_Number                                                                  Winning_Numbers  Extra_Numbers  Kicker
     1500844   (3, 9, 11, 16, 25, 26, 28, 29, 36, 40, 41, 46, 63, 66, 67, 69, 72, 73, 78, 80)            NaN       2
     1500845   (6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 23, 29, 30, 39, 42, 47, 50, 51, 56, 62, 63, 66, 75)            NaN       2
     1500846   (2, 9, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24, 28, 38, 40, 41, 44, 50, 55, 57, 61, 65, 68, 72, 76)            NaN       1
     1500847  (9, 10, 22, 25, 28, 36, 40, 45, 46, 47, 52, 54, 57, 58, 59, 65, 69, 70, 74, 79)            NaN       2
     1500848   (7, 9, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 24, 25, 27, 34, 40, 41, 42, 47, 49, 50, 53, 71)            NaN       2

print(type(df.Winning_Numbers.loc[0]))
>>> tuple

print(type(df.Winning_Numbers.loc[0][0]))
>>> int

# if you absolutely need Winning_Numbers to be a list
df.Winning_Numbers = df.Winning_Numbers.apply(list)
```

- Writing this back into a csv, will not maintain the `type`

  - Try [Prevent Reprocessing with HDFStore](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#prevent-reprocessing-with-hdfstore) to maintain `types`

Comment: So is it impossible to create a CSV file that is able to store a list or array of integers? I was hoping I would be able to translate this file afterwards into a TFRecord File. Should I use a different file format?

Comment: You can still save it as a csv, but you'll have to fix the type at import again.  CSV files don't maintain the type.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can commonly happen when saving and loading pandas DataFrames as `.CSV files`(using `to_csv()`), which is a text format.So, it can't contain the type of your object.

If you want to maintain the type you can pickle the object (If is it pickable!)

Or while reading from CSV you can read that column as list

```py
db.loc[:,'Winning_Numbers'] = db.loc[:,'Winning_Numbers'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
```